# Quote escape in Java JSP

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp

I am using Google Translate.

The following occurs.
I'm picking up a web project developed in Java long long ago.
Now I am in the process of migrating the project to the new technologies and platforms.

The problem is that when I do the migration for Eclipse Moon (latest version), I use Apache Tomcat 8 and Java jre1.8 and I host running my program, when I go to a page JSP where is an assignment to the attribute pasasdo by java code ie

EXAMPLE:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <html: text property = "<% =" value ("+ variable +" _ "+ variable +") "%>" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I run the program I understand that the value inside the quotes must be escaped, i.e. I would have to modify and replace `"` with `\"`

EXAMPLE:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <html: text property = "<% = \" value ("+ Variable + \" _ \ "+ Variable + \") "%>" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Can I work on the entire project without having to escape the quotes, I mean leave them as they are, is there any way to avoid or ignore this issue because the project has 390 JSP pages, and it would be very tedious enter each and escape ALL the quotes.

I hope you have understood me, basically working in JSP without having to escape quotes if you can do that.

Comment: Please, no more `!! HELP !!` business as your question is no more important than any other on this site. To get quick attention to your question, you will instead want to write as clear a question as possible, one that is easy to answer.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a "forum" as you may be used to — a Question should just pose the question with any necessary information included, but without conversational text.

Answer (score 0):

You would not escape the quotes in this situation because your quotes here are not inside a Java `String` but are actual Java code.

You can either

(1) Just use single quotes for the HTML attribute:

```
<html:text property='<%=" value (" + variable + " _ " + variable + ") "%>' />
```

(BTW, make sure to get rid of the erroneous space.  Its `<%=` not `<% =`. And you have other spacing issues.)

(2) Prepare the whole thing in a variable first:

```
<%
String val = " value (" + variable + " _ " + variable + ") ";
%>
<html:text property="<%=val%>" />
```

(3) Stop using scriplets and use JSTL/EL:

```
<html:text property="value (${variable} _ ${variable})" />
```